# Read data from Elite 100 energy meter using RS 485 MODBUS with ARduino mega

Tags: arduino, modbus, rs485

I'm trying to read 4 Registers from a  Energy Meter (Model no: ELITE 100, Make : SECURE), using Arduino Mega. I'm using RS 485 to TTL module for arduino to communicate with the Energy meter. After uploading the code,in serial monitor I saw that arduino fails to communicate with the energy meter, and show the response code in hex format is "E2". I unable to understand what is the actual problem. Please help me.

Energy Meter MODBUS Register link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1kTQg0wvcX-iG7jkeZHwIUkK8e-9VVVW_?usp=sharing

Some settings values are:
Parity Bit: None, Baud Rate : 9600 , Stop Bit  : 1

CODE Output is:  `Failed, Response Code: E2`

```c
 #include<ModbusMaster.h>
    
    /*  DI =  UNO / NANO TX PIN / arduino mega pin 1 TX pin
                RO =  UNO/ NANO RX PIN / arduino mega pin 0 RX Pin
    */
    #define MAX485_DE      3
    #define MAX485_RE_NEG  2
    
    ModbusMaster node;
    
    void preTransmission() {
      digitalWrite(MAX485_RE_NEG, 1);
      digitalWrite(MAX485_DE, 1);
    }
    
    void postTransmission()
    {
      digitalWrite(MAX485_RE_NEG, 0);
      digitalWrite(MAX485_DE, 0);
    }
    
    void setup() {
      pinMode(MAX485_RE_NEG, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(MAX485_DE, OUTPUT);
      // Init in receive mode
      digitalWrite(MAX485_RE_NEG, 0);
      digitalWrite(MAX485_DE, 0);
    
    
    
      Serial.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1);
      //slave ID 1
      node.begin(1, Serial);
    
      Serial.println("Starting Modbus Transaction:");
      node.preTransmission(preTransmission);
      node.postTransmission(postTransmission);
    }
    
    uint16_t newData = 0;
    float floatData;
    double dataOne;
    
    void loop() {                           // loop starts from here.
      static uint32_t i;
      uint8_t j, result;
      uint16_t data[10];
    
      i++;
      result = node.readHoldingRegisters(40172, 2); // read holding registars
    
      Serial.println(" ");
      /*
        if (result == node.ku8MBSuccess) {
    
          Serial.print("\nSuccess, Received data 0: ");
    
          for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {    // THIS FUNCTION READ SINGLE REGISTAR
            data[j] = node.getResponseBuffer(j);
            floatData, dataOne = node.getResponseBuffer(j);
            Serial.print("\nHex data:");
            Serial.print(data[j], HEX);
            Serial.print(" ");
            Serial.print("\nDec data:");
            Serial.print(data[j], DEC);
            Serial.print("\nfloat data:");
            Serial.print(floatData);
      */
    
      if (result == node.ku8MBSuccess) {
    
        Serial.print("\nSuccess, Received data 0: ");
    
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
          data[j] = node.getResponseBuffer(j);
        }
    
        unsigned long temp = (unsigned long)data[0] + (unsigned long)data[1] * 65536;
        floatData = *((float*)&temp);
    
        Serial.print(floatData);
    
      }
    
      //}
      //}
    
      else {
        Serial.print("Failed, Response Code: ");
        Serial.print(result, HEX);
        Serial.println(" ");
        delay(5000); // 5000
      }
      delay(1000);
    
    }
```

Comment: My guess would be that `40172` means command `4` (Read Input Registers) register 172. See "Modbus: When 40001 Really Means 1, or 0 Really Means 1" in [this document](https://www.csimn.com/CSI_pages/Modbus101.html) for info.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value of holding register as mentioned in Link:  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1kTQg0wvcX-iG7jkeZHwIUkK8e-9VVVW_?usp=sharing

to read V1: R Phase to Neutral Voltage subtract 1 in initial address means
40100 - 1 = 40099 and pass only 99 to the code Ex. node.readHoldingRegisters(99, 2)

Hope it work and also thanks to [Brits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11810946/brits)